# is mi notebook 14 graphics card switchable

Tags: windows, video-card

I want to buy a mi notebook 14. In the spec sheet it says it has a Nvidia graphics card. I know a few friends who bought a laptop with dedicated graphics card, but they cant change the graphics card system wide. There is a way to change the graphics card for a specific applications, but I don't want that. So I want to ask, Is there a way to change graphics cards system wide?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to add a graphics card to a laptop, but it's not for gaming purposes. Strange as it might sound, you can plug one in to a USB port. Doing this gives you an extra graphics output so you can drive an external monitor as well as your laptop's built-in screen. If your laptop already has a VGA, DisplayPort or HDMI output, adding a USB graphics card means you can drive a third screen: you're not limited to two displays.

For example, this StarTech adapter gives your laptop an HDMI output: https://www.amazon.co.uk/StarTech-com-External-Video-Monitor-Adapter/dp/B00H91BRZU/ref=sr_1_fkmr0_2?tag=pcagenius-21&ie=UTF8&qid=1521109083&sr=8-2-fkmr0&keywords=Startek%20USB%20graphics%20card&ascsubtag=06-3364133-11-0000000&geniuslink=true